# Showing Image in ImageButton

Tags: android, android-studio, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I added an Image to ImageButton but it doesn't show.why?

```
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8-fast-forward-64" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_text" />
```

Comment: @drawable/icons8-fast-forward-64 is this the image location?

Comment: If you found my answer correct can i ask you to click the tick on the left hand side of the answer to say it's correct. For more information on what to do when someone answers your question click here: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem ly's in your naming of the drawable....

Refactor it to read `icons8fastforward64` from `icons8-fast-forward-64`

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/next_button"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icons8fastforward64" 
        android:contentDescription="@string/next_text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code look like fine, check your `drawable` resource. Does it show on `xml` layout file??